# What version of visual studio is visual studio online using?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

What version of visual studio is visual studio online using?

I see the MS build version is currently set to MS Build 14.0 in my project but will it automatically move to VS 2017 at some point? Do I have control over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Team Services (previously known as Visual Studio Online) is TFS.

And TFS 2017 was released a while ago, alongside VS2017 RTM came TFS 2017 Update 1.

And VSTS is consistently ahead of the on premise version. See the [Visual Studio Team Services Features Timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/features-timeline) for what is in VSTS, what is planned, and what TFS version will get that feature.

> but will it automatically move to VS 2017 at some point?

You might need to configure something, but it is coming soon. Eg. [Tweet from Buck Hodges yesterday](https://twitter.com/tfsbuck/status/839489661424791553):

> 3. The VS 2017 build pools (US & Europe) will start rolling out next week (I was overly optimistic for those I told it would be this week).